# MySQL return Deadlock with insert row and FK is locked 'for update'

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I get deadlock error in my mysql transaction.

The simple example of my situation:

```
Thread1 > BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Thread1 > SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID=1000 FOR UPDATE;
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Thread2 > BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Thread2 > INSERT INTO B (AID, NAME) VALUES (1000, 'Hello world');
[Hangs]

Thread1 > INSERT INTO B (AID, NAME) VALUES (1000, 'Hello world2');
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Thread2 >
Query OK, 1 row affected (10.00 sec)
```

B.AID is a FOREIGN KEY referring to A.ID

I see three solutions:

1. catch deadlock error in code and retry query.
2. use innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog in my.cnf
3. lock (for update) table A in Thread2 before insert

Is there any other solutions ?

Comment: I can;t see why this would be a deadlock and your title mentions FK's. Is there a foreign key relation between A and B that you didn't mention

Comment: @Elemental: Yes, there is a foreign key. OP mentioned this, but in somewhat cryptic way. I've modified post to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what code surounds this examples, but it might be worth using `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` for both Threads, since you're not actually updating the row itself. If you must use `LOCK FOR UPDATE`, I would think that locking the other thread would be the only logical path.

Also if you open to moving away from MySQL, I've found that PostgreSQL has much better resolution of deadlocks. In some cases, I was finding MySQL deadlocked every time when running the same script on >1 thread. Where the same script in PostgreSQL could handle it just fine for any number of parallel threads.

Comment: +1. Although it doesn't look like the best solution, it's much better than LOCK FOR UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a function from the [mysql high performance blog.](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/02/25/pitfalls-of-converting-to-innodb/)

I was able to implement the following deadlock handling code in PHP:

```
/* maximum number of attempts for deadlock */
$MAX_ATTEMPS = 20;

 /* query */
 $sql = "INSERT INTO B (AID, NAME) VALUES (1000, 'Hello world')"; 

 /* current attempt counter */
 $current = 0;

 /* try to query */
 while ($current++ <$MAX_ATTEMPS) 
 {
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     if(!$result && ( mysql_errno== '1205' || mysql_errno == '1213'  ) )
         continue;
     else
         break;
 }  
 }
```

Hopefully this might give you some good ideas.

Comment: It might be good solution when there is the only INSERT statement in the transaction. But in general it's not acceptable since you have to repeat whole bunch of action since transaction is started, which might span several functions (methods).

Answer (score 0):

There are no deadlocks here, what version of MySQL and what isolation level do you use?
I got these results, adding timestamp column to table B:

```
Thread1 > BEGIN;

Thread1 > SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID=1000 FOR UPDATE;
/* 0 rows affected, 1 rows found */

Thread2 > BEGIN;

Thread2 > INSERT INTO B (AID, NAME, date) VALUES (1000, 'Hello world', NOW());
[Hangs]

-- after 5 seconds

Thread1 > INSERT INTO B (AID, NAME, date) VALUES (1000, 'Hello world2', NOW());
/* 1 rows affected, 0 rows found */

Thread1 > COMMIT;

Thread2 > COMMIT;
```

B will contain 2 rows that look like:

1. 1000 'Hello world' '2011-06-11 19:23:15'
2. 1000 'Hello world2' '2011-06-11 19:23:20'

The situation you described takes place only when B.NAME is unique index and you are trying to insert the same values. The first insert waits for A.ID index to be released which will never happen because of duplicating value for B.NAME.